# Составление словаря типа число-метод

Tags: python

Всем привет. Вопрос такой: есть куча подпрограмм и в определенный момент времени с плк  в Python приходят число и по этому числу должна выполняется определенная подпрограмма. Пример: 1 - test_1(), 2- test_2() и тд. Как это в Python элегантно можно реализовать? Думал словарь,но на место значения записать метод нельзя.

Comment: почему нельзя? `{1: test_1, 2: test_2, ...}`

Comment: Что такое *плк*?

Comment: программно логический контроллер. в промышленности используется

Comment: @MaxU так не работает же

Comment: `funcs = {1: test_1, 2: test_2, ...};`, потом запускаем так: `funcs[1]()` или `funcs[1](param1, param2, ...)`

Comment: @IvanMatskevich если подпрограмма=функция, то всё работает https://repl.it/repls/LuxuriousMadeupTriggers

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно нужно создать словарь такого вида:

```
{1 : test_1, 2 : test_2, 3 : another_method}
```

Главное не ставить скобочки, потому что если поставить метод выполнится и запишется результат (то, что метод вернул).